# How do I get Maven to successfully build my JAR file

Tags: java, apache, maven, jar

When I do a `mvn clean install`, I get the **Warning** -

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ cucumber-selenium ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/user/ij-workspace/cucumber-selenium/cucumber-selenium/target/cucumber-selenium-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I've read up on the directory structure I am supposed to have, but I don't see what is wrong with mine (see attached image). I removed the Main package, I don't see why not. 
Many thx in advance,
[image]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-selenium</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>cucumber-selenium</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>acceptance-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Runner.class</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml?

Comment: The jar typically contains the *production* code, in src/*main*/java. No-one cares about the testing code used to test the library you're publishing as a jar.

Comment: @delephin I added the POM.xml in my original question. I just added the pertinent stuff.

Comment: Just in case you really want to have your test classes packed into a JAR file have a look at this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: Your folders `java` and `resources` should be inside a `main` folder. Thats all it took for my project to stop showing that warning message.